# Content after CSS overlay is below the overlay

Tags: html, css, overlay

I'm learning some basic css and am trying to make an overlay without having to set the height on the overlay div. (I want the overlay to cover just the background image in the `.bg-img` class)

But the problem is that the content after the overlay is behind the overlay.
https://jsfiddle.net/vxbu07z9/10/

Can someone point out what I'm missing?

**html**:

```css
.bg-img {
  background-image: url('https://placeimg.com/600/600?t=3');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.content {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, labore!</div>
    <ul>
      <li>List Item 1</li>
      <li>List Item 1</li>
      <li>List Item 1</li>
      <li>List Item 1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing Stackoverflow snippet functionality. No need for external code sites.

Comment: There is no image loading.

Comment: You need to set `z-index`. [Stacking context.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a stacking order issue.

## You can fix it by adding `position:relative` to the `.content` div

to reset the order

```css
.bg-img {
  background-image: url('https://placeimg.com/600/600?t=3');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.content {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img">
  <div class="overlay">

  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, labore!</div>
    <ul>
      <li>List Item 1</li>
      <li>List Item 1</li>
      <li>List Item 1</li>
      <li>List Item 1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

or more simply..

## Change the `z-index` of the overlay

```css
.bg-img {
  background-image: url('https://placeimg.com/600/600?t=3');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: -1;
}

.content {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, labore!</div>
    <ul>
      <li>List Item 1</li>
      <li>List Item 1</li>
      <li>List Item 1</li>
      <li>List Item 1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `z-index` hides the overlay entirely but the `position:relative` works! Can you update your answer?